# Extract specfic stats from fabric.io

Tags: curl, google-fabric

Is it possible to extract stats from fabric.io using curl or any api in order to fetch that information ? I want to extract daily active users, daily new users and other statistics.

Comment: Anyone please share your views about it ?

Answer (score 0):

Mike from Fabric here. There are no public APIs currently available for Fabric. There are exports for some data as [referenced](https://docs.fabric.io/apple/answers/export-data.html) here.

Daily Active Users
Daily New Users
Monthly Active Users
Crash-free Users
User Sessions
Average Sessions per user.

Simply click the arrow in the top-right corner of a chart to download up to a year’s worth of data into a CSV file.

Comment: Thank you @Mike. I got your point but I need real time stats for that purpose. What can i do if i want to get sum of `ACTIVE USERS` of all apps in real time ? On the other hand I got some stats using option in inspect element(network tab) `copy as curl` But it takes too much time and work to gather data using 'copy as curl'.

Comment: We don't have support for a real-time export of information currently within Fabric.